# TypeScript: mix in plain object into class

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, vue-class-components

Basically I'm trying to create a function that dynamically defines class that extends another class from passed object. Something like this:

```
const ObjectMixin = function<T>(obj: T): new () => T {
    return class extends BaseClass {
        ...obj // pseudo code to convey the idea 
    }
}
```

Goal of this is to be able to write Vue class components with mapped state mixed in. Like this:

```
class MyComponent extends ObjectMixin(smartModule.mapState(['someState'])) {
    created() {
        this.someState // should not give any errors
    }
}
```

I almost got it working with hacks

```
interface ObjMixinI {
    <T>(obj: T): new () => T
}

const ObjectMixin: ObjMixinI = obj =>
//@ts-ignore
    function() {
        //@ts-ignore
        Object.assign(this, obj)
    }
```

But I can't make it extend Vue plus it's obviously a horrible solution.

Comment: please share reproducible example with `smartModule`

Comment: that's what I'm asking to help with....

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the `constructor` like this:

```
const ObjectMixin = function<T>(obj: T) {
    return class extends BaseClass {
        constructor() {
            super();

            Object.assign(this, obj);
        }
    } as { new (): BaseClass & T }
}

class X extends ObjectMixin({ test: 42 }) { }
const x = new X();
console.log(x.test);
```